# How can I make Multiple inequalities?

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

How can I make multiple inequalities in python? for example.

```
school_type = input ("Enter what type of school you want. press H for high school, M for middle school, or E for elementary school").lower()

while school_type != "h" or school_type != "m" or school_type != "e": # Is this code correct?

   print ("You must enter H, M, or E")
```

Answer (score 3):

`school_type != "h" or school_type != "m"` will always evaluate to `True` because `school_type` will always be either not equal to `"h"` or not equal to `"m"`.

You should be using `and` in your while-loop condtion instead of `or`:

```
while school_type != "h" and school_type != "m" and school_type != "e":
```

That, or you could use [`not in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

```
while school_type not in {"h", "m", "e"}:
```

Answer (score 2):

As @iCodez just said, you want to iterate again if the `school_type` is something different from `"h"`, and something different from `"m"` and something different from `"e"`. And as he said, this is better expressed with something like `school_type not in ["h", "m", "e"]`. That expression is simpler, easier to read and less error-prone.

After you change the `while`'s condition, there are still two things that I'd fix in your code. First, if the condition is true, that is, the user typed a wrong value for `school_type`, a proper action should be taken: The user must be asked to type a new value, until he/she types a correct one. Second, you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. The difference is the first one is better suited for strings, while the second one is problematic, and in this cases actually requires the user to type the `"` around the input value.

The resulting could be something like this:

```
def ask_for_school_type():
    s = "Enter what type of school you want. Type H for high \
school, M for middle school, or E for elementary school: "
    return raw_input(s).lower()

school_type = ask_for_school_type()
while school_type not in ["h", "m", "e"]:
   print "You must enter H, M, or E"
   school_type = ask_for_school_type()
```